# При использовании аннотации ModelAttribute не работает реализация метода Create

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

Помогите пожалуйста понять, в чем моя ошибка. Ломаю голову уже второй день. По задумке при переходе на url /create/new должна открываться html форма , где нужно ввести Имя и нажать на кнопку create, за кулисами должна происходить запись данного имени в условную Базу данных*(ArrayList)* и перенаправлять на страницу /people с отображением списка всех людей, находящихся в базе данных.

По факту открывается только страница для записи имени, но при нажатии create появляется ошибка 404.

Ссылка на проект:

https://github.com/voiatile/People.git

Если заменить реализацию метода create с такой:

```
@PostMapping()
    public String create(@ModelAttribute("person") People person) {
       
        peopleDao.save(person);
        return "redirect:/people";

    }
```

на такую, то все работает как надо.

```
@PostMapping()
public String create(@RequestParam ("name") String name) {
    People person = new People();
    person.setName(name);


    peopleDao.save(person);
    return "redirect:/people";
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, ты можешь сделать аннотацией @RequestBody, чтобы не передавать это в ссылке и кидать json:

```
public String create (@RequestBody People person)
```

Json:

```
{"id":"1","name":"people_Name"}
```